# JavaFX center an image doesn't work

Tags: java, image, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I am having a problem.
I am trying to create an FXML(image) which I will use within another another FXML file. In the image FXML I want to change the image and center it, so I always want the image to be in the center, but it doesn't work.
I am having this right now:

```
<fx:root fx:id="vBox" alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity"   maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
          <ImageView fx:id="imageView" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
    </children>
</fx:root>
```

Can someone help me with this? 
This image sticks to the left side.

Answer (score 1):

```
fx:id="vBox" type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox"
```

Change your container to `StackPane` and it will center your image automagically.